# Make mergetool PhpStorm on Windows 10

Tags: git, windows-10, phpstorm, mergetool

How do I make PhpStorm my Git mergetool on Windows 10?

```
git config --global merge.tool phpstorm
git config --global mergetool.phpstorm.cmd 'phpstorm.exe \"$BASE\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$MERGED\"'
```

Comment: Have a look at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/command-line-merge-tool.html for the parameters. Then I guess you need to configure your local git to use that (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mergetool). P.S. Not using it this way myself so cannot add anything more than just links.

Comment: Also check: https://gist.github.com/jmlane/6877474, https://gist.github.com/jvandyke/4355099